# let user press button only one time

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton

I want to let user give +1 with one button or -1 points with another button, but they should be able to only press one of these buttons one time...

I use this code, but the user can still click on the button multiple times...

```
var job: Job! {
    didSet {
        jobLabel.text = job.text
        likeButton.setTitle(" \(job.numberOfLikes)", for: [])
        dislikeButton.setTitle(" \(job.numberOfDislikes)", for: [])
    }
}

@IBAction func dislikeDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    (dislikeDidTouch).isEnabled = false
    job.dislike()
    dislikeButton.setTitle(" \(job.numberOfDislikes)", for: [])
    dislikeButton.setTitleColor(dislikeColor, for: [])    }

@IBAction func likeDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    sender.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    job.like()
    likeButton.setTitle(" \(job.numberOfLikes)", for: [])
    likeButton.setTitleColor(likeColor, for: [])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sender is a `UIButton` , it's better to construct the funcs like this

```
@IBAction func dislikeDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton)
@IBAction func likeDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton)
```

and inside each one do

```
sender.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: perfect, it works, thank you :) could I may ask you how I can deactivate for example the dislike button, if the user already tapped on the like button?

Comment: When the user clicks like action , use **dislikeButton.isEnabled = false**  as sender here only represents **likeButton**